# what is the default admin console password for Jboss EAP 6

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

what is the default admin console password for Jboss EAP 6..?

Its not allowing me to see the administration console without password. And I can't find the configuration page also.

Please advice.

Answer (score 13):

1. go to JBOSS_HOME\bin, run the add-user script, add an Management User

   > What type of user do you wish to add?
   >
   > a) Management User (mgmt-users.properties)
   >
   > b) Application User (application-users.properties)
   >
   > (a): a
   >
   > Enter the details of the new user to add.
   >
   > Realm (ManagementRealm) : ManagementRealm
   >
   > Username : *yourname*
   >
   > Password : *yourpassword*
2. you will get an secret value after you add the user successfully

   ```
   To represent the user add the following to the server-identities definition <secret value="*somevalue*" />
   ```
3. add this secret to the JBOSS_HOME\domain\configuration\host.xml

   ```
   <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
       <authentication>
           <local default-user="$local" />
           <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
       </authentication>
       <server-identities>
           <secret value="*somevalue*" />
       </server-identities>
   </security-realm>
   ```
4. you can login to the admin console use that new added username and password

Comment: Nice answer to another question! at least you should have mentioned that there's no default password and then start your complete explanation.

Comment: It should have been mentioned that steps 2 and 3 are only necessary if the user is used for inter-AS connection, i.e. you answered the respective question of add-user script with 'yes'.

Comment: Yes, there is no default user exists in jboss, so we need to add it manully.

Answer (score 10):

You need to add a user to access the admin console in JBoss, to do so..

1. go to ***JBOSS_HOME\bin***
2. run the ***add-user*** script
3. add as a management user.

You are ready to go and access the admin console at http://{localhost:9990}. Hope it helps.

Comment: It asks what groups I want to add *this* user to... what should I do?

Comment: I'd like to add that with Google Chrome (version 71.0.3578.80), this does not work and will only display "The management interface could not be loaded.
Authentication required." With Firefox and IE 11 it works. Possibly I have some missing Kerberos setting in Chrome...

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned before, there is no default value, you just have to create it by Invoking the add-user.sh or add-user.bat script.

[Here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Installation_Guide/chap-Getting_Started_with_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform_6.html) you will find the documentation from Redhat... which is basically what the above answers stated... I would like just to highlight the step 3 on the documentation:

> **3. Choose the realm for the user.**
>
> The next prompt refers to the realm where the user will be added. **For**
>   **a user with permissions to manage JBoss Enterprise Application**
>   **Platform 6, choose the default, which is ManagementRealm**.

If you need access to the console, just leave the default realm.